# Descargar html a imagen con dom to image manteniendo estilo mask de css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Agradezco quien me pueda ayudar con el siguiente caso, estoy buscando descargar una sección de html a imagen manteniendo el efecto mascara aplicado desde css, el código que tengo primero captura la sección y la convierte a imagen pero no mantiene el estilo de mascara agregado mediante css en el cual hay dos imágenes, una que corresponde al fondo y otra que genera el efecto de mascara.

Comparto el código y estaré muy agradecido de la ayuda

Este es el código html donde se carga la imagen de fondo con un id htmlcapture para usar en el JavaScript

`código HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>


<div class="container">
    <div id="htmlcapture" class="img-container">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/kenobi22v/image/upload/v1702388169/img-muestrax600_c5htid.png"
            class="mask" />
    </div>
    <button onClick="htmlToImg()">HTML to Image</button>
    <button onClick="imgDown()">Download</button>
    <img src="" id="showImg">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Aquí el código CSS donde se encuentra el efecto mascara que carga la imagen que se utilizará para el efecto.

`código CSS`

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(133deg, #171f1a, #3c57d2);
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  width: 768px;
}
.img-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
.mask {
  mask: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/kenobi22v/image/upload/v1702388167/ejemplologocreativotwitter_zvcxlo.webp)
    no-repeat;
}
#htmlcapture {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Este es el código JavaScript donde primero se captura el html a imagen y posteriormente se puede descargar como archivo .png

`código JS`

```
var node = document.getElementById("htmlcapture");

function htmlToImg() {
  domtoimage
    .toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      /*var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);*/
      document.getElementById("showImg").src = dataUrl;
      imgUrl = dataUrl;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("oops, something went wrong!", error);
    });
}

function imgDown() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = imgUrl;
  a.download = "htmlToImg.png";
  a.click();
}
```